# How to have Sphinx pdf text generated from double-backticks resemble the output of the html (red text with a frame)?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

Using double-backticks around a block of text in my restructuredtext sphinx document causes the HTML output to display the text in red with a frame around it. I would like to have my latexpdf output look the same. The pdf shows the text in a mono font in black and with no frame. At a minimum, I would like the text to be in a red color.

My .tx file shows that it uses \sphinxcode{\sphinxupquote{my text}}. Do I need to somehow override sphinxupquote or is there another way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of how you would like the output to look like? Also, could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the packages and macros you're using :)